# react native how to create a dummy bottom tab bar

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am just trying to add a dummy bottom nav bar with four buttons that don't really do anything. I know it's a weird question...

Here is my App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';

import Home from './screens/HomeScreen';
const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator({

  HomeScreen: { screen: Home,
    navigationOptions: ({ navigate })=> ({
      header: null,
    }),
  }

});

const App = createAppContainer(AppNavigator);

export default App;
```

It doesn't need to do anything, it just needs to show up on every screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this one

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from 'react-navigation-tabs';
import Home from './screens/HomeScreen';

const Dummy = () => {
  return <View />;
};

const HomeNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  HomeScreen: { screen: Home,
    navigationOptions: ({ navigate })=> ({
      header: null,
    }),
  },
});

const AppNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
  Tab1: {
    screen: HomeNavigator,
  },
  Tab2: {
    screen: Dummy,
  },
  Tab3: {
    screen: Dummy,
  },
  Tab4: {
    screen: Dummy,
  },
});


const App = createAppContainer(AppNavigator);

export default App;
```

Comment: This is a good first step, but I don't think it'll work because I need to export my `stackNavigator` as well. Is there a way I can add this to my `stackNavigator`?

Comment: You mean you need your above stack on every tabs?

Comment: no no, what I need is just to have the tab-bar be presented, but not usable. Your code is close, however using it would mean I won't be able to use my stackNavigator (where the actual project would be presented)

Comment: Not sure that I got your idea, but you can add `StackNavigator` inside `TabNavigator` or vice versa. I updated code above

Comment: I added your stack inside tab1, so tabs will be show up when you navigate inside your stack